# "The requested resource is not available" is shown in my java web application

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I was trying to create a web app in eclipse with the help of a tutorial. I have done the same code given there. But HTTP status 404 is shown. In error log "Could not launch in profiling mode because no profilers are configured" is shown. For your convenience I am giving the code snippet.

This is my PersonBeanModel.java class

```css
package com.za.tutorial.mvc;

public class PersonBeanModel {
 
 private String p_name=null;
 private String P_password=null;
 

 public String getP_name() {
  return p_name;
 }


 public void setP_name(String p_name) {
  this.p_name = p_name;
 }


 public String getP_password() {
  return P_password;
 }

 public void setP_password(String p_password) {
  P_password = p_password;
 }
 
 public void do_something()
 {
  setP_name("["+getP_name()+"]");
  setP_password("["+getP_password()+"]");
 }





 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

}
```

This is my ServletController.java

```css
package com.za.tutorial.mvc;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ServletController
 */
@WebServlet("/ServletController")
public class ServletController extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ServletController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

 /**
  * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  */
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  PersonBeanModel person=new PersonBeanModel();
  person.setP_name(request.getParameter("p_name"));
  person.setP_password(request.getParameter("p_password"));
  person.do_something();
  request.setAttribute("person", person);
  getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("jspView.jsp").forward(request, response);
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
 }

 /**
  * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  */
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  doGet(request, response);
 }

}
```

And this is my jspView.jsp

```css
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<jsp:useBean id="person" scope="request" class="com.za.tutorial.mvc.PersonBeanModel" />
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>My first mvc</title>
</head>
<body>
 Name: <jsp:getProperty name="person" property="p_name" />
 <br/>
 Password: <jsp:getProperty name="person" property="p_password" />
</body>
</html>
```

For your

Comment: You need to install TPTP. You can find it from this url by using eclipse-.install new software http://download.eclipse.org/tptp/updates

Comment: Please add the code of your web.xml file

Comment: please replace `getServletContext()` by `request`